# nightmare js: get json response from POST request

Tags: javascript, post, request, nightmare

I am using nightmare to login to a page and click a few links. Then I go to a specific url for which a `POST` request is made. I want to retrieve the json response from the POST request.
So far, I have this

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
nightmare
    .goto('https://my.url/')
    .type('#user_id', 'myUserId')
    .type('#password', 'passw0rd')
    .click('#button-login')
    .wait(3000)
    .goto('specific-url') // this URL loads a page with some data
    .end()
    .then(console.log)    // this prints stuff like HTTP response: OK
    .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
});
```

When I go to the `specific-url`, a POST request is made and the page is populated with data. I can see the page load properly but I want the data in Json format because I don't wanna parse the page.

Any ideas on how to retrieve the response json?

Comment: I think this is more server-side problem, did you send the response with JSON-header set?

Comment: @Sepultura I don't have access to server-side data. I can see the Json in chrome dev console, in Networks Tab.

Comment: when you open the url in the web-browser it should actually be displayed as json, if not I think you have to parse it manually. If you're using jQuery you can do it with $.parseJSON(string)